# How to include stylesheet in laravel 6.2

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to include stylesheet in my project .But it shows an error like this http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7B%7B%20url('css/style.css')%20%7D%7D.
Please help me to solve this.

Comment: how are you trying to add the css file?? show us some code.

Comment: is this in a `.blade.php` file?

Comment: Can you please add more code line to easily readable.

Comment: I got it when I saved as blade.php .Thank you

Comment: @ani Please add more code. Where you have included stylesheet?

Answer (score 1):

Include the CSS file into your blade template in laravel:
if your CSS file stored in the `public` folder:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}" >
```

if you have stored CSS file outside public folder:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('path/css/style.css') }}" >
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure if you want a view to be parsed as Blade that it has a `.blade.php` file extension.

> "Blade view files use the `.blade.php` file extension ..." [Laravel 6.x Docs - Blade Templates - Introduction](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/blade#introduction)

The `%7B` in your URL is `{` and `%7D` is `}` so the blade echo, `{{ ... }}` have not been parsed because your file is not a `.blade.php` file.